# How to prevent infinite reloads when selecting multiple allergens in a Next.js 13 and React 18 client-side filter form?

Tags: react-hooks, next.js13, react-18

I work with next js 13 app directory. I have a page on which i have filters in a cliend side react component. When I pick more than one alergens from my filter form the page goes into infinite reloading

I need to find a way to stop this reload behaviour when more than one alergens are selected from the form

```
const MeniSideNavbar = ({
  minPrice,
  maxPrice,
  addresses,
  uniqueTypes,
  allAlergens,
  modal,
  id,
}: {
  minPrice: number;
  maxPrice: number;
  gotvaci: GotvacInterface[];
  uniqueTypes: string[];
  addresses: string[];
  allAlergens: string[];
  modal: boolean;
  id: string;
}) => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const dateInRouter = searchParams.get("date");
  const typeInRouter = searchParams.get("type");
  const dostavaInRouter = searchParams.get("dostava");
  const priceInRouter = searchParams.get("price");
  const alergeniInRouter = searchParams.get("alergeni");
  const ratingiInRouter = searchParams.get("rating");
  const addressInRouter = searchParams.get("address");
  const dostapnoPoPorachkaInRouter = searchParams.get("dostapnoPoPorachka");

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    rawPickedDate: dateInRouter ? dateInRouter.toString() : undefined,
    type: typeInRouter ? typeInRouter : "",
    dostava: dostavaInRouter ? dostavaInRouter : undefined,
    dostapnoPoPorachka: dostapnoPoPorachkaInRouter
      ? Boolean(dostapnoPoPorachkaInRouter)
      : undefined,
    price: priceInRouter ? Number(priceInRouter) : undefined,
    address: addressInRouter ? addressInRouter : "",
    alergeni: alergeniInRouter ? alergeniInRouter : undefined,
    rating: ratingiInRouter ? ratingiInRouter : undefined,
  });

  const handleClearFiltersClick = () => {
    setPickedPrice(undefined);
    setState({
      rawPickedDate: undefined,
      type: "",
      dostava: undefined,
      dostapnoPoPorachka: undefined,
      price: undefined,
      address: "",
      alergeni: undefined,
      rating: undefined,
    });
  };

  const [pickedPrice, setPickedPrice] = useState<number | undefined>(
    state.price && state.price
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);

    state.address
      ? params.set("address", state.address)
      : params.delete("address");

    state.rawPickedDate
      ? params.set("date", state.rawPickedDate)
      : params.delete("date");

    state.dostapnoPoPorachka
      ? params.set("dostapnoPoPorachka", state.dostapnoPoPorachka.toString())
      : params.delete("dostapnoPoPorachka");

    state.type ? params.set("type", state.type) : params.delete("type");

    state.rating ? params.set("rating", state.rating) : params.delete("rating");

    state.dostava
      ? params.set("dostava", state.dostava)
      : params.delete("dostava");

    state.alergeni
      ? params.set("alergeni", state.alergeni)
      : params.delete("alergeni");

    pickedPrice
      ? params.set("price", pickedPrice.toString())
      : params.delete("pickedPrice");

    searchParams.toString !== params.toString &&
      router.replace(`/meni?${params}`);
  }, [
    state.rawPickedDate,
    state.address,
    state.dostapnoPoPorachka,
    state.type,
    state.rating,
    state.dostava,
    state.alergeni,
    pickedPrice,
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dateInRouter
      ? setState({ ...state, rawPickedDate: dateInRouter })
      : setState({ ...state, rawPickedDate: "" });
  }, [dateInRouter]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`${
          !modal
            ? "col-md-4 col-lg-3 d-none d-md-block sticky-top overflow-auto vh-100"
            : "modal-body"
        } py-3 bg-white`}
      >
        {!modal && <h2 className="h3 mb-3">Филтри:</h2>}
        <div className="position-relative pb-3">
          <select
            style={{ backgroundSize: "20px" }}
            value={state.address}
            className="form-select px-4 rounded-3 border-0 shadow py-2"
            onChange={(e) => setState({ ...state, address: e.target.value })}
          >
            <option value="">Локација</option>
            {addresses.map((address) => (
              <option key={`addressForModal-${address + id}`} value={address}>
                {address}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <i
            style={{ top: "5px", left: "5px" }}
            className="bi bi-geo-alt-fill position-absolute h5 text-danger mb-0"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="position-relative mb-3">
          <select
            style={{ backgroundSize: "20px" }}
            value={state.type}
            className="form-select px-4 rounded-3 border-0 shadow py-2"
            onChange={(e) => setState({ ...state, type: e.target.value })}
          >
            <option value="">Вид на храна</option>
            {uniqueTypes.map((type) => (
              <option key={`typeForModal-${type + id}`} value={type}>
                {type}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <i
            style={{ top: "5px", left: "5px" }}
            className="bi bi-geo-alt-fill position-absolute h5 text-danger mb-0"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="pb-4 border-bottom">
          <div className="form-check mb-2 px-2">
            <input
              className="form-check-input float-end rounded-circle fs-5"
              type="checkbox"
              value={new Date().toLocaleDateString()}
              id={`dostapno-vednas${id}`}
              checked={
                state.rawPickedDate === new Date().toLocaleDateString()
                  ? true
                  : false
              }
              onChange={(e) => {
                if (state.rawPickedDate !== new Date().toLocaleDateString()) {
                  setState({
                    ...state,
                    rawPickedDate: e.target.value,
                    dostapnoPoPorachka: undefined,
                  });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, rawPickedDate: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />
            <label
              className="form-check-label float-start me-2 fs-5"
              htmlFor={`dostapno-vednas${id}`}
            >
              Достапно веднаш
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-check mb-2 px-2">
            <input
              className="form-check-input float-end rounded-circle fs-5"
              type="checkbox"
              value={new Date(
                +new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) + 86400000
              ).toLocaleDateString()}
              id={`dostapno-utre${id}`}
              checked={
                state.rawPickedDate ===
                new Date(
                  +new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) + 86400000
                ).toLocaleDateString()
                  ? true
                  : false
              }
              onChange={(e) => {
                if (
                  state.rawPickedDate !==
                  new Date(
                    +new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) + 86400000
                  ).toLocaleDateString()
                ) {
                  setState({
                    ...state,
                    rawPickedDate: e.target.value,
                    dostapnoPoPorachka: undefined,
                  });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, rawPickedDate: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />
            <label
              className="form-check-label float-start me-2 fs-5"
              htmlFor={`dostapno-utre${id}`}
            >
              Достапно утре
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-check px-2">
            <input
              value={
                state.dostapnoPoPorachka
                  ? state.dostapnoPoPorachka.toString()
                  : ""
              }
              className="form-check-input float-end rounded-circle fs-5"
              type="checkbox"
              id={`dostapno-po-poracka${id}`}
              checked={state.dostapnoPoPorachka ? true : false}
              onChange={() => {
                if (!state.dostapnoPoPorachka) {
                  setState({
                    ...state,
                    dostapnoPoPorachka: true,
                    rawPickedDate: undefined,
                  });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, dostapnoPoPorachka: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />
            <label
              className="form-check-label float-start me-2 fs-5"
              htmlFor={`dostapno-po-poracka${id}`}
            >
              Достапно по порачка
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="py-3 px-2 border-bottom position-relative">
          <p className="label fs-5">Филтрирај по цена:</p>
          <input
            style={{
              appearance: "none",
              backgroundColor: "#fe724d",
              borderRadius: "50px",
            }}
            className="w-100 fs-5 fs-5"
            type="range"
            role="progressbar"
            aria-label="Example with label"
            aria-valuenow={state.price ? state.price : 0}
            aria-valuemin={minPrice}
            aria-valuemax={maxPrice}
            min={minPrice}
            max={maxPrice}
            value={state.price ? state.price : 0}
            onMouseUp={(e) => setPickedPrice(Number(state.price))}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setState({ ...state, price: Number(e.target.value) })
            }
            step={1}
          />
          {state.price && <small>{state.price} ден</small>}
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between mt-2">
            <p className="mb-0">{minPrice} ден.</p>
            <p className="mb-0">{maxPrice} ден.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Accordion className="py-0 px-2 border-bottom">
          <Accordion.Item className="border-0" eventKey={id}>
            <Accordion.Header className="fs-5">Алергени</Accordion.Header>
            <Accordion.Body className="px-0">
              {allAlergens.map((alergen, index) => (
                <span key={"key" + alergen + index + id}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="btn-check"
                    id={`${alergen + id}`}
                    checked={
                      state.alergeni ? state.alergeni.includes(alergen) : false
                    }
                    value={alergen}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      const allergen = e.target.value;
                      const allergens = state.alergeni
                        ? state.alergeni.split(",")
                        : [];

                      if (e.target.checked) {
                        allergens.push(allergen);
                      } else {
                        const index = allergens.indexOf(allergen);
                        if (index !== -1) {
                          allergens.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                      }

                      const updatedAlergeni = allergens.join(",");
                      setState({
                        ...state,
                        alergeni: updatedAlergeni || undefined,
                      });
                    }}
                  />
                  <label
                    className={`btn btn-danger text-white mb-2 me-2 shadow-sm ${
                      typeof state.alergeni === "string" &&
                      state.alergeni.includes(alergen)
                        ? "text-decoration-line-through"
                        : null
                    }`}
                    htmlFor={`${alergen + id}`}
                  >
                    {alergen}
                  </label>
                </span>
              ))}
            </Accordion.Body>
          </Accordion.Item>
        </Accordion>
        <div className="py-3 border-bottom px-2">
          <p className="fs-5">Покажи по рејтинг:</p>
          <div className="ps-0 form-check mb-2">
            <input
              className="form-check-input float-end fs-5"
              type="radio"
              value="3"
              name="rating"
              id={`rating-3${id}`}
              checked={state.rating === "3"}
              onClick={(e) => {
                if (state.rating !== "3") {
                  setState({ ...state, rating: "3" });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, rating: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />
            <label
              className="pe-5 form-check-label d-flex align-items-center fs-5"
              htmlFor={`rating-3${id}`}
            >
              <Rating
                readOnly
                name="size-medium"
                defaultValue={3}
                max={3}
                size="medium"
                className="text-danger me-auto"
              />
              3+
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="ps-0 form-check mb-2">
            <input
              className="form-check-input float-end fs-5"
              type="radio"
              name="rating"
              id={`rating-4${id}`}
              value="4"
              checked={state.rating === "4"}
              onClick={() => {
                if (state.rating !== "4") {
                  setState({ ...state, rating: "4" });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, rating: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />

            <label
              className="pe-5 form-check-label d-flex align-items-center fs-5"
              htmlFor={`rating-4${id}`}
            >
              <Rating
                readOnly
                name="size-medium"
                defaultValue={4}
                max={4}
                size="medium"
                className="text-danger me-auto"
              />
              4+
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="ps-0 form-check">
            <input
              className="form-check-input float-end fs-5"
              type="radio"
              name="rating"
              id={`rating-5${id}`}
              value="5"
              checked={state.rating === "5"}
              onClick={() => {
                if (state.rating !== "5") {
                  setState({ ...state, rating: "5" });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, rating: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />
            <label
              className="pe-5 form-check-label d-flex align-items-center fs-5"
              htmlFor={`rating-5${id}`}
            >
              <Rating
                readOnly
                name="size-medium"
                defaultValue={5}
                max={5}
                size="medium"
                className="text-danger me-auto"
              />
              5
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="pt-3 px-2">
          <div className="form-check ps-0 mb-2">
            <input
              className="form-check-input float-end fs-5"
              type="radio"
              name="dostava-modal"
              id={`dostava${id}`}
              value="dostava"
              checked={state.dostava === "true"}
              onClick={() => {
                if (state.dostava !== "true") {
                  setState({ ...state, dostava: "true" });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, dostava: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />
            <label
              className="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center pe-5 fs-5"
              htmlFor={`dostava${id}`}
            >
              <p className="mb-0 fs-5">Достава</p>
              <i className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center height-30px width-30px ms-auto bi bi-truck text-danger rounded-circle shadow-sm" />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-check ps-0">
            <input
              className="form-check-input float-end fs-5"
              type="radio"
              name="dostava-modal"
              id={`rating-podiganje${id}`}
              value="podiganje"
              checked={state.dostava === "false"}
              onClick={() => {
                if (state.dostava !== "false") {
                  setState({ ...state, dostava: "false" });
                } else {
                  setState({ ...state, dostava: undefined });
                }
              }}
            />
            <label
              className="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center pe-5 fs-5"
              htmlFor={`rating-podiganje${id}`}
            >
              <p className="mb-0 fs-5">Подигање</p>
              <i className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center height-30px width-30px ms-auto bi bi-truck crossed text-danger rounded-circle shadow-sm" />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        {!modal &&
          (state.address ||
            state.alergeni ||
            state.dostapnoPoPorachka ||
            state.dostava ||
            state.rating ||
            state.type ||
            state.rawPickedDate ||
            state.price) && (
            <>
              <div className="d-flex pt-3">
                <button
                  onClick={handleClearFiltersClick}
                  className="btn btn-warning text-white bg-opacity-75 border-0 w-100 me-2"
                >
                  Исчисти филтри
                </button>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
      </div>
      {modal && (
        <div className="modal-footer">
          <button
            onClick={handleClearFiltersClick}
            className="btn btn-warning text-white bg-opacity-75 border-0 me-2"
          >
            Исчисти филтри
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

I think the issue is in my useEffect hook but I can't find a way to solve it